# How to get all Json Body's Children, Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, decode

may i ask , if my json body has multiple Children like this.

```
 { "head": {    "title": "Podcasts",
    "status": "200"}, "body": [
 { "element" : "outline", 
"text" : "Music", 
"children": [
 { "element" : "outline", 
"type" : "link", 
"text" : "Schlager", 
"URL" : "http://opml.radiotime.com/Browse.ashx?id=c100000594&filter=p:topic", 
"guide_id" : "c100000594" },
 { "element" : "outline", 
"type" : "link", 
"text" : "Rádios da Metropolitana FM", 
"URL" : "http://opml.radiotime.com/Browse.ashx?id=c100002153&filter=p:topic", 
"guide_id" : "c100002153" },
 { "element" : "outline", 
"type" : "link", 
"text" : "Hits Popular", 
"URL" : "http://opml.radiotime.com/Browse.ashx?id=c100000599&filter=p:topic", 
"guide_id" : "c100000599" },
 { "element" : "outline", 
"type" : "link", 
"text" : "Top 40 & Pop Music", 
"URL" : "http://opml.radiotime.com/Browse.ashx?id=c57943&filter=p:topic", 
"guide_id" : "c57943" },
] },
 { "element" : "outline", 
"text" : "Talk", 
"children": [
 { "element" : "outline", 
"type" : "link", 
"text" : "International Public Radio", 
"URL" : "http://opml.radiotime.com/Browse.ashx?id=c100001487&filter=p:topic", 
"guide_id" : "c100001487" },
 { "element" : "outline", 
"type" : "link", 
"text" : "History Podcasts", 
"URL" : "http://opml.radiotime.com/Browse.ashx?id=c100000897&filter=p:topic", 
"guide_id" : "c100000897" },
 { "element" : "outline", 
] }
] }
```

and my code can get just the first Child.

```
List<Prodcasts> parseProdcasts(String responseBody) {
  var parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody)['body'][0]['children'] as List;
  return parsed.map<Prodcasts>((json) => Prodcasts.fromJson(json)).toList();
}
```

cause i typed `['body'][0]['children']` and if i want to get the second Child i must type `['body'][1]['children']`

ok, but what if i want to get all the Children?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get children you need map function.

```
jsonDecode(responseBody)['body'].map((item)=> item['children']).toList().expand((x) => x).toList()
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help . 
i got this error 

Exception: type '(dynamic) => String' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => Iterable<dynamic>' of 'f'

i want to get the text value from all the children ; =>text = json['text'];

Comment: json.map((child)=> child['text']).toList() will give you the list of the text in children

Comment: thanks really for your time, but as i said i got an error message that i mentioned before after i used the map func , can you please try your funktion with the json here http://opml.radiotime.com/Browse.ashx?render=json&c=podcast     and if it worked please paste your code , to see where is the different between my code and yours and know the wrong that i made. thanks again